# jQuery- Target specific link with href value where number changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script here I am trying to target a specific link where href is very specific but issue is there is a number and that number changes depending on number of categories forum has. I don't know any dynamic way to overcome this issue.

Code I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var total_posts = _userdata["user_posts"];
    var minimum_posts = 5;

    if (total_posts < minimum_posts) {
        $('a[href="/post?f=1&mode=newtopic"]').css("pointer-events", "none")
    }

});
```

Pay attention to targeted element. I have f=1, but it can be any number, depending on category. How can I target all possible links with this href no matter what number comes after f?

Comment: Try `$('a[href*="/post?f="][href*="&mode=newtopic"]').css(....` OR `$('a[href^="/post?f="][href$="&mode=newtopic"]').css(....`   * means contains , ^ means starts with , $ means ends with